# Date from NSDate is null after converting

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I need to convert String as a date and then preset it in a UILabel. When I do this like below, I get null string and the UILabel is also null. What is wrong in this code?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, YYYY HH:mm:ss"];

 NSDate *dateFromString;
 dateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:[tmpDevice valueForKey:@"date"]]; //This string is from array of object and is not null

     NSString *stringFromDate  = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateFromString];

     NSLog(@"%@", stringFromDate); // here is null

     [cell.dateOfAddedCell setText: stringFromDate]; // and here also is null
```

Comment: Can you show us what `[tmpDevice valueForKey:@"date"]` is ?

Comment: What's the point of converting the string to a date and then converting the date back to the same string? That seems pointless. Side note - do not use `YYYY`, use `yyyy` for the year.

Comment: Doesn't a null value indicate an error on parsing the string?

Comment: This is my date in miliseconds as a string: 1406141698811

Comment: @OwenHartnett there is no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, you have a string representing the milliseconds. You first need to convert that string to an `NSDate`. Then you can format the `NSDate` into the desired string.

You neglect to mention the epoch for your value but it appears to be based on the standard January 1, 1970 epoch.

```
NSString *millisString = tmpDevice[@"data"];
NSTimeInterval seconds = [miliisString doubleValue] / 1000;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"]; // notice is yyyy, not YYYY
NSString *stringFromDate = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"%@", stringFromDate);

cell.dateOfAddedCell.text = stringFromDate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line:

dateFromString = [dateFormat dateFromString:[tmpDevice valueForKey:@"date"]];

with something like:

dateFromString = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[(NSNumber *) [tmpDevice valueForKey:@"date"] intValue]];

Your code is not working because [tmpDevice valueForKey:@"date"] should return something like:

@"May 25, 20145 19:30:00"

but not:

1406141698811

in case you wish to use the method:

dateFromString

Hope it makes sense